# JQuery extract subdomain and pass to a variable

Tags: jquery

I need to extract a sub domain and pass to a variable to then add into a url so that a link will work on a number of different environments

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var sub_domain = window.location.split('.')[0].split('//')[1];`

This should do the trick.  this line of code will get current url, then will split it using "." as a separator, then will take first part. and then get rid of "http://".   so if current url is "http://maps.google.com/" script will return "maps".   However if there is no subdomain it will return domain instead.